# Is addSubview:view needed if I create the view hierarchy in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have succesfully created a view hierarchy programmatically. I now want to replicate this hierarchy using Interface Builder (IB) instead.

In IB I have nested a UIView within the main Window. Do I now nolonger need the following in method applicationDidFinishLaunching:application:

```
[window addSubview:controller.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Notes:
controller is a member of my UIApplicationDelegate subclass.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will not need to add it programmatically. If the view appears within the window in IB, it is automatically being added as a subview when the nib loads. In fact, you shouldn't even need to call `[window makeKeyAndVisible]` if your window is set up properly in IB.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't need addSubView here.  Make sure that the correct nib file is loaded, that is the view associated with the Window for a window based app.